# How to get the response title from the "jqXHR" object using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my AJAX error function:

```
error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
        alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
        alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
        alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
        alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
        alert('Time out error.');
    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
        alert('Ajax request aborted.');
    } else {
        //var test = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
        alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
    }
}
```

Here in this `jqXHR.responseText` gives me response like

> {"status":{"statusCode":555,"title":"Please provide the
>   recipient","class":"requestController"}}

From this suppose I want to display only the *title* from this response in  alert box how can I do this?

I tried with `jqXHR.status`, but it's giving me the *status code*. Also  `jqXHR.title` is giving me `undefined` value.

So please anybody tell me how can I extract this particular field from the response.

Comment: add errorThrown with your error function. You will get value of title in errorThrown variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `jqXHR.responseText` is JSON, so you want to use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert it into a JavaScript object literal access the `title`:

```
var respJson = JSON.parse( jqXHR.responseText );
console.log( respJson.status.title ); // will print out "Please provide the recipient"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the JSON from the response text in order to get the contained attributes:

```
var response = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
alert(response.status);
```

If this does not work, make sure the server responds with the correct content header

`Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8`

Comment: I tried this also..its giving me output as[object object] and i wrote that Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 in ajax call correctly.

Comment: Sorry, the correct alert is: `alert(response.status.title);`

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the responseText of the response, and then access the title with `error['title']`
`

```
const error = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
console.log(error['title']);
```

Also, you can get more details by looping through the errros array and capture the values.

```
$.each(error['errors'],
   (key, value) => {
      console.log(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `jqXHR.responseJSON`:

```
error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
    ...
    } else {
        alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseJSON.status.title);
    }
}
```

> If `json` is specified, the response is parsed using `jQuery.parseJSON`
> before being passed, as an object, to the success handler. The parsed
> JSON object is made available through the `responseJSON` property of
> the `jqXHR` object.

Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/